# How do I document Rake tasks with YARD?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rake, yard

I would like to include information on the Rake tasks in our Rails app. We use [YARD](http://yardoc.org) for documentation, and at the moment pages like `lib/tasks/development.rake` show up by default as unformatted text.

I can make them render as Ruby source code using the `# @markup ruby` [from the YARD documentation](http://www.rubydoc.info/gems/yard/file/docs/GettingStarted.md#Adding_Meta-Data_to_Extra_Files).

However, this just renders any comments inline, even if they include YARD directives like `# @!method foo`. This means [the YARD documentation on tagging DSLs](http://www.rubydoc.info/gems/yard/file/docs/GettingStarted.md#Documenting_DSL_Methods) doesn’t seem to be applicable.

Am I missing something?

How can I get YARD to recognise code vs documentation in `.rake` files?

N.B. I would be happy with a solution that ignores the actual code and just generates documentation copy, but the source for the documentation copy must be the `.rake` file itself – I do not want documentation to live in a separate `.markdown` file (or whatever) as there’s too much chance of it getting out of sync.

**More info - the `yard` command:**

I am using a `.yardopts` file containing the following:

```
--asset graphs 'app/**/*.rb' 'lib/**/*.rb' - README info/*
```

To get YARD to read the Rake tasks I can add `'lib/tasks/*.rake'` *after* the hyphen (i.e. add Rake files to the YARD ‘Files’ list), but as noted above this does not process them correctly.

As per Benjamin’s suggestion below, I tried adding `'lib/tasks/*.rake'` *before* the hyphen (i.e. add Rake files to the list of regular Ruby files to be processed), but this doesn’t seem to generate anything at all.

It is possible YARD is generating something but not in the expected location / with the expected filename I suppose, I’m not familiar enough with how YARD works to figure out if there is orphaned output somewhere. There is certainly nothing appropriate coming up in the search that YARD generates, and a simple `find doc | grep rake` or `find doc | grep basename_of_rake_file` doesn’t show anything.

Comment: Is this simply a matter of getting Yard to recognize `*.rake` files as ruby?

Comment: I’m afraid I haven’t looked at this much since asking, but I suppose essentially it is, yes. However, actually _specifying_ that they are Ruby with the `# @markup ruby` directive doesn’t work because it _only_ renders the Ruby, i.e. it no longer processes documentation comments

Comment: @Leo, does specifying the rake extension on the command line help? _yardoc *.rake -o out/_ ?

Comment: ... and maybe using the _AT note_ tag?

Comment: @benjamin just tried these, and I’m afraid they don’t seem to work. It works adding `lib/tasks/*.rake` to the _files_ section of the `yardoc` command, but then it only reads them as text (as per the question). Adding them to the body of the command doesn’t seem to generate anything for those files at all, i.e. nothing is listed in the Yard class/method/file lists, and there doesn’t seem to be anything in the output `doc/` directory. Anywhere else I should look for output?

Comment: I’ve added some more details on the YARD options I’m using...

Answer (score 3):

From [YARD](http://www.rubydoc.info/gems/yard/file/docs/GettingStarted.md#Using_YARD_to_Generate_Documentation) documentation:

In the **Getting Started Guide with YARD** section under **Using YARD to Generate Documentation**, check out  *Documenting Extra Files* or *Adding Meta-Data to Extra Files*. It might help.